# Magnetic Flux in single surface

Tags: magnetic-fields

Can the magnetic Flux in single surface (surface has two dimensions)  be negative?.  If can what does negative magnetic Flux mean

Comment: Can you be more specific in your question? In particular, do you want to:
1.) Calculate the flux through a 1-D surface in 2-D space, or
2.) Calculate the flux through a 2-D surface in 3-D space?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Magnetic flux is defined as $\int \vec{B}\cdot d\vec{A}$, which requires the arbitrary choice of the orientation of the area normal vector $d\vec{A}$. Once the direction of $d\vec{A}$ is chosen, then a positive flux is oriented in the direction of $d\vec{A}$, while a negative flux is oriented in the opposite direction.

Even in a closed surface, there is still a choice of orientation. The difference is that there is a conventional choice of orientation (choose the outward-facing normal) in those situations, but you could still decide that inward flux was positive if you wanted. You'd get a bunch of negative signs elsewhere in the theory, though, so people generally don't do that.

Comment: Also, in looking up part of this question, flux is only well-defined on orientable surfaces. You can't really define flux on a Mobius strip, as per the discussion here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/51169/flux-through-a-mobius-strip

Comment: Good but how can I choice of the orientation of the area normal vector for single surface

Comment: @malek, an 'ant' walking along a closed path on a 2-D surface can choose to keep the surface normal to her left ([right-hand rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right-hand_rule#Coordinates)) or to her right (left-hand rule).

Comment: @Alfred-Centauri Wrong orientation convention - that's for path integrals, not for surface integrals. For a non-closed surface, the choice is entirely arbitrary; as long as you declare what your choice is, nobody should have a problem with it.

Comment: probably_someone, I don't follow your objections.  (1) I mention that it's a choice (note the word choose) and (2) the orientation convention seems correct to me. Consider, for example, Ampere's law.  The CCW closed line integral, in the $xy$, plane of the magnetic field is proportional to the current through the surface bounded by the path with surface normal in the $+z$ direction, i.e., the   the bounded surface and its normal are 'to the left' of the path.

Comment: @Alfred-Centauri My main objection was that your convention was irrelevant for surface integrals, as calculating the flux of a 2-D surface embedded in 3-D space involves a surface integral, not a line integral. But I just realized that maybe we're interpreting the question differently. Let me check.

Comment: probably_someone, [here's](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fA5Kv.png) more or less what I'm thinking of if my wording is less than satisfactory.  I found this slide after a brief search [here](http://faculty.nps.edu/pstanica/Teaching/Chap16_Sec8&9.pdf)

Comment: @AlfredCentauri Yeah, but all you've done here is choose the normal vector orientation based on the direction you walk around the boundary. So how does one choose the direction you walk around the boundary? Isn't that still arbitrary in these situations?